# changing plot size in R

Tags: r

`plot(lin_model)`

Trying to plot my linear model, but the outcome is too small.

[image]

I am new to R and I wasn't able to find the option to change the size in the plot() documentation.

Comment: are running it inside rstudio?  The plot size is basically a function of the size of the device you output to.  So is determined by the size of the window

Comment: i am using azure notebook

Comment: Not familiar with azure.  But the same principle still holds - R will make the plot fit whatever device you output to, so this should be adjusted from within the notebook. - maybe this helps https://gallery.azure.ai/Notebook/Changing-R-plot-options-in-Jupyter-6